# Nuxt `npm run dev` crashed with odd characters

Tags: node.js, server, nuxt.js, knex.js, koa

I created an application with `koa/nuxt`/`knex` around 1 year ago... about 3 days ago it stopped working and as a temporary solution I decided to simply restart the application in dev mode to log a couple of things but I am not able to start it on my server anymore and I get some odd characters.

Locally I was able to start the application without a sweat (or almost: since my server is in maintenance mode I discovered that I was not doing a couple `null` checks which were missing, but no big deal).

Does anyone know how to fix this, how I could provide more data or has any suggestions to give about how to inspect this?

[image: Zalgo, is that you?]

Comment: check out all files to see if there are any strange invisible characters... maybe with some hexeditor. You could also try to run your code through some auto formatter like prettier or clang-format and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of things happened:

- Another process in the server started to request more and more RAM
- A peak of connections happened

This lead the `nodemon` to a crash.

Trying to restart the `nodemon` via dev environment (`npm run dev`) also triggered a local build, which (with no surprise) requests RAM... since the other process was still active, this resulted in the build process misbehaving.

Solutions were:

- Build locally, ship the built version which in my case simply meant to just use `npm run start` again. (which was still not enough for me in order to understand what caused the issue in the first place)
- Stop the memory-consuming process
- Get more RAM